# Is $top supposed to be murdering odata.nextlink?

Tags: pagination, odata, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm attempting to access the odata api in a Microsoft CRM 2011 product. It's working mostly as expected, except that if $top is used then odata.nextlink goes missing. This means that it's impossible to set the paging to some user-defined value (it looks like it's default to paging at 50 anyway, but given the nature of the data they were wanting 5/10/25). The odata.nextlink value is present as long as $top isn't used.

Is this some idiosyncrasy of CRM 2011? Has it somehow been configured to behave this way? I'm just a developer (maintainer, really) trying to make use of the API, I have zero experience with Dynamics and only found out recently that it was the framework for this software (or that there was such a thing as Dynamics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461(v=crm.5).aspx#BKMK_top) this is expected. Perhaps you should filter client side in this situation.

> **$top**
>
> Determines a maximum number of records to return.
>
> If you are retrieving additional sets of data using the next link you
>   should not change the $top query option value because this will cause
>   unpredictable results.